# How to sort a nsarray with CLLocations from north west to south east?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, geolocation, cllocation

I want to sort an array with CLLocations so that the locations are sorted how they are going to be placed on the map.

I mean the first item of the array is the most North-West location and the last location is the moest South East.

Here is what I have thus far:

```
NSArray* stack = [locations sortedArrayUsingComparator:^(CLLocation* a, CLLocation* b) {

  if ( a.coordinate.latitude < b.coordinate.latitude ) {
    return NSOrderedDescending;
  }
  if ( a.coordinate.latitude > b.coordinate.latitude ) {
    return NSOrderedAscending;
  }

  return NSOrderedSame;
}];
```

What would be a simple way to accomplish this? thanks.

Comment: Still trying to figure this one out. Seems its a little more difficult then i thought. Google does not have an answer either...

Comment: What exactly does "how they are going to be placed on the map" mean?  Why does the order of the locations matter?

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I am not using MapKit as rendering engine for the map. I have an own implementation of a map. And i want to draw the markers (CALayers) in particular order.

I you look at this image:
http://blogs.bookassist.com/blogs/industry/uploaded_images/IMG_0181-746691.PNG (not mine)

The markers are drawn in particular order (north west to south east) so that bottom of the marker is not drawn on top of the head of another marker. (MapKit does this by default.).

Comment: That code seems fine but need to compare longitude after checking the latitude (assuming you want to order the locations from west to east and then move down to the next lower latitude -- ie. same direction that words are read in English).